# Python: pyQt, Qthread and matplotlib: subplots crash at the second call

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am trying to draw graphs with the result of a thread using matplotlib. First I launch the thread using a pyqt button, all is ok. But the second time I press the button, subplots crash because I suppose tuples can't be modified. This is my simplfied code that you can try and see by yourself:

> ```
> from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import numpy as np
> from PyQt4.Qt import *
> import sys
>
> class thread(QThread):
>   def __init__(self, parent=None):
>       QThread.__init__(self, parent)
>
>   def __del__(self):
>       self.wait()
>
>   def render(self):
>       self.start()
>
>   def run(self):
>       data = [(1, 10), (3, 100), (4, 1000), (5, 100000)]
>       data_in_array = np.array(data)
>       transposed = data_in_array.T
>       x, y = transposed
>       fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
>       ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
>       ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')
>       plt.show()
>
> class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
>    def __init__(self):
>         QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
>         self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
>         self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
>         layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
>         layout.addWidget(self.button)
>         self.thread=thread()
>
>    def handleButton(self):
>         self.thread.render()
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
>   window = Window()
>   window.show()
>   sys.exit(app.exec_())
> ```

Please, how can I solve it to avoid crash and uses several times my button?
Thanks

Comment: All plotting must be done on the main thread due to the QT restriction that only the main thread can drive the painting of the screen.

Comment: Ok tcaswell, I didn't know about this restriction... but could you show me how you would have done on this little example to avoid the problem? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to mix your Qt application and Matplotlib (which uses Qt in its backend).

See https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html for a better explanation than I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, was searching solution.

By adding these 3 lines solved the issue. Please add these 3 lines before importing pyplot

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['backend'] = "qt4agg"
mpl.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = "PySide"
```

Comment: If you get any other solution, please share it with me. I am looking for a solution to this problem.